# why the js I import in my component dosen't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-cli

I have Jquery function in mt angular navbar, those function doesn't seems to work once I route link to another component but those function are important for my navbar to be used, so I put them in a js file that I added to my angular.json script field so it can be loaded even when I route to a another componenet, but now I don't know why when I try to use my function containing my jquery code it doesn't work.

navabr.component.ts

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from "../auth.service";
import {clientType} from "../clientType";
import {navbarutil} from './navbarUtilities.js';
declare var $;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css'],
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    navbarutil.switchstate(); //launch with a collapsed navbar
    navbarutil.unwindOnCollapsed();
    navbarutil.buttonSwitch();
  }

 
}
```

navabrUtilities.js

```js
function unwindOnCollapsed() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.collapsed').click(() => {
      console.log('hey '+this.isOpen());
      if (!(this.isOpen())) {
        this.switchstate()
      }
    });
  });
}

function buttonSwitch() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bouttonmenunavbar').click(() => {
      this.switchstate();
    });
  });
}

function switchstate() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('yes');
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('fliph');
    $('.innerlist').collapse('hide');
  });
}

function isOpen() {
  return $('.sidebar').hasClass('fliph');
}
```

angular.json

```js
"scripts": [
           "./src/app/navbar/navbarUtilities.js"
            ]
```

could you help me find how to make them work ?

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? Is there an error or the behaviour expecting is not?

Comment: I have ERROR ReferenceError: "switchstate is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

```
function buttonSwitch() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bouttonmenunavbar').click(() => {
      this.switchstate();
    });
  });
}
```

Ths problem might be here `this.switchState()`. The context of `this` is the function of document. You have to write an arrow function in order to get the this of your class which contains the method `switchState`.

```
function buttonSwitch() {
  $(document).ready(() => { // here is the modification
    $('#bouttonmenunavbar').click(() => {
      this.switchstate();
    });
  });
}
```